# Android studio, design preview not working with neumorphism library

Tags: java, android-studio

Whenever i used neumorphism library, design preview went completly blank, although i can drag and drop everything, just i am not able to see this...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOLfr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I36I.png)

I tried almost everything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found solution on github.
There is some bug in Dolphine version of Android.
To use neumorphism library, There are two options...
Either write all the colors manually in colors.xml which required in this library.
Or update your android studio to giraff or downgrade your android studio to Chipmunk.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, try to using a different layout like LinearLayout and see if that helps.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working, But i found solution on github. There is some bug in dolphine version of android, For using neumorphism library i needed to add colors mannualy in colors.xml file and it solves